# How to insert html using the insertAfter method along with fadeIn effect so that the html just fades In

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried inserting some html and at the same time giving it an effect of fadeIn. This is how I attempted to achieve it, but it failed:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="Jquery.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.container{
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
<div class="container"><img src="001.jpg" alt="sasuke"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
$("<p>lorem Ipsum blah blah </p>").insertAfter("img").fadeIn(1500);

})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create the element hidden when you add it to the DOM, then fade it in:

```
(function(){
  var paragraph = $("<p>");
  paragraph.text("lorem Ipsum blah blah");
  paragraph.hide();
  paragraph.insertAfter("img");
  paragraph.fadeIn(1500);
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably have to hide it to be able to fade it in:

```
$(function(){
    $('<p />', {text: 'lorem Ipsum blah blah '}).hide().fadeIn(1500).insertAfter("img");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/DfLZe/)

Comment: The fadeIn() should really be after the insertAfter().  Even though asynchronously this would work just fine.  It's not intuitive.

Comment: I've experienced issues with fading in after inserting, so I usually do the fadeIn before the insertion of the element, and it works just fine, that's what chaining in jQuery is for, chaining methods, and in my opinion, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 (function(){
     $("<p style="display:none;">lorem Ipsum blah blah </p>").insertAfter("img").fadeIn(1500);
 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
(function(){
   $("<p>Fade in text </p>").hide().fadeIn(1500).insertAfter("img");
})();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skhj335g/)